# BeforeMount not working on a computed method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mount

Hello i have a problem whenever i reload my page i want to call a beforeMount() method to call my filterRecords (computed method) so that i can receive the data ,but it is just not working fine it is telling me that filterRecords is not a function.

My computed:

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      sec: "sec"
    }),
    createdDate() {
      return moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY ");
    },
    createdHours() {
      return moment().format("HH:mm ");
    },
    filteredRecords() {
      return this.records.filter(record => {
        return record.template_id === this.sec;
      });
    }
  },
```

so i just do this:

```
beforeMount() {
    this.filteredRecords();
  },
```

it is not calling it so i get nothing to my filteredRecords.

how am i able to call it when i reload the page ( i am recieving the records data from an API rails)

Comment: Computed Properties can not be called with parentheses. Remove them to get the computed property, otherwise Vue will look for a method with that name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure to check the Vue docs about computed properties.

You should not call them as functions, but as properties (since they are *computed* properties).

You can try to console log `filteredRecords` in the `beforeMount` hook like this:

```
beforeMount() {
   console.log(this.filteredRecords)
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a fundamental misunderstanding on how Computed properties work. Computed properties are accessed the same way you would access props or data on a component. They are consumed as values, not as methods. A big hint to this fact is that you're calling `map**Getters**`

You could consume `filteredRecords` in your template something like:

```html
<div v-for="record of filteredRecords" :key="record.someKey">...</div>
```

or by assigning it to a data property
`this.records = this.filteredRecords`

Comment: could you please clarify  what do you mean be asssigning it to a data property?

Comment: Yes. Say you have a component with the key `records` in data, initialized to an empty array. In `mounted`, putting `this.records = this.filteredRecords` would assign the value of `filteredRecords` to the key `records`. Then, you could iterate `records` in the same way as I described in my `v-for` example in my answer. I don't think this offers any benefit over just accessing `filteredRecords` in this case, but does well enough to serve as an example of what you could do with a computed property.

Comment: thank you,  but i just really can seem to find my solution , all i want to do is to call my filteredRecords,  so i can loop through it but it just not calling it or it is not receiving the data  the original data array receives  data from API with a get request can it be the case that it is just  getting the things from API slower even though my get request is in my created(){}  ?